# How to merge object and array in one controller laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got like this

[
{
"NameProduct": "iphone",
"IDProduct": 1,
"ListPrice": 100000,
"ImagePath": "iphone.png"
},
[
{
"IDCollection": 5,
"NameCollection": "Phone",
"Description": "my description",
}
],
{
"NameProduct": "SamSung",
"IDProduct": 2,
"ListPrice": 379000,
"ImagePath": "samsung.png"
},
[
{
"IDCollection": 5,
"NameCollection": "Phone",
"Description": "my description",
}
],

But I want like this:

```
{
  "IDCollection": 5,
  "NameCollection": "Phone",
  "ProductList": [
    {
        
        "NameProduct": "iphone",
        "IDProduct": 1,
        "ListPrice": 100000,
        "ImagePath": "iphone.png"


    },
    {
        
        "NameProduct": "SamSung",
        "IDProduct": 2,
        "ListPrice": 100000,
        "ImagePath": "samsung.png"
    },
  ]
}
```

This is my code:

```
    public function show(int $id)
    {
        $product=[];
        $product_collection = CollectionProduct::where('IDCollection',$id)->get();
        $collection = Collection::where('IDCollection',$id)->get();
            foreach ($product_collection as $items) { 
                    $x = Product::select('NameProduct','IDProduct','ListPrice')->find($items['IDProduct']);
                    $x->ImagePath = ProductImage::where('IDProduct',$items['IDProduct'])->first()['Path'];
                    array_push($product, $x,$collection); 
            }
        return response()->json($product);
    }
```

and idea how do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eager Loading to get the relationships of CollectionProduct. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

For help you with the code I need to see your relationships  of the DB but I think this can help you:

```
public function show(int $id)
{
    $product_collection = CollectionProduct::with('collection.product.productImage')
                                            ->where('IDCollection',$id)
                                            ->get();

    return response()->json($product_collection);
}
```